# Vue3 + Vite dynamic import fails in production build

Tags: vue.js, vite

One of my components load dynamically another component by (simplified):

```
const loadedPanel = shallowRef<unknown | undefined>();

loadedPanel.value = defineAsyncComponent(() => import("./AdjustFontsGlobal.vue"));

<component :is="loadedPanel" />
```

It works perfectly in development, but in production there is a mismatch between the number attached to the end of the filenames. That is, `npm run build` creates `/assets/AdjustFontsGlobal-c1dc97d2.js` and `AdjustFontsGlobal-ec3f476f.css`.

But as soon as I execute the code above it fails with:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:3322/assets/AdjustFontsGlobal-3a401f68.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Error: Unable to preload CSS for /assets/AdjustFontsGlobal-3a401f68.css
    at HTMLLinkElement.<anonymous> (index-3bd1e9ff.js:230:18581)
GET http://127.0.0.1:3322/assets/AdjustFontsGlobal-a5f9b046.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Also the numbers changes at every run, without any rebuild. So renaming the generated files does not help.

I have read the difference in build tool (`esbuild` vs. `rollup`), between dev and production and even tried the suggested solution (defining the key `external` in `rollupOptions` of `vite config.js` without any difference. But the behavior seems a "little" extreme.

Is there hope or should I load statically the `AdjustFontsGlobal` and the other components?

Thanks!

mario

Comment: You can try to change the `publicPath: "./"` attribute in the `vue.config.js` file, and then repackage.

Comment: Mmmm... The directory is correct, is the file name that is different.