# Browser caching issue with code-splitting in production? (Failed to fetch dynamically imported module)

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, single-page-application, vite, code-splitting

I'm using Vue + Vite for my web app, and I use code-splitting in my router file for most of the routes, for example:

```
 {
 path: "settings",
 name: "settings",
 component: () => import("../views/SettingsView.vue"),
 },
```

On build, the .js output file for the component gets added a hash in its name (I want to keep that), such as `SettingsView-4eff3305.js`

Every time I build and push to production and then navigate through the app, I get this error: `TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module`, since the browser has cached the files from the previous build so now it's looking for the old `SettingsView-4eff3305.js` although now it might be called `SettingsView-4eff9999.js`.

A window reload fixes it, but that's not the ideal solution - it's not user friendly.
I also don't want to keep the old build alongside the new one until the browser decides to start using the new one. Ideally, with each new release, the users should immediately be able to use the newest features instead of waiting that their browser cache expires.

I'm looking for ways to correctly address this issue for production.

My thought is to catch that failed dynamic import error upon navigation and tell the router to look for the correct file name instead.

I found that in the router I can catch the error as such:

```
router.onError((error, to) => {
    if (error.message.includes('Failed to fetch dynamically imported module'))
    {
     ...do something 
    }
})
```

And with Vite I can generate a manifest.json file upon build, and that file will contain all the hashed names for the app's components.

My `vite.config.ts` file:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "@": "/src",
        },
    },
    server: {...},
    build: {
        manifest: true,
    },
});
```

and a snippet of the `manifest.json` file for my `SettingsView.vue` component:

```
"src/views/SettingsView.vue": {
    "file": "assets/SettingsView-5d4722b3.js",
    "imports": [
      "index.html",
      "_InputError.vue_vue_type_script_setup_true_lang-434b0fff.js"
    ],
    "isDynamicEntry": true,
    "src": "src/views/SettingsView.vue"
  },
```

In the error caught in `router.onError((error, to)` I get *some* info that could be helpful. I can `console.log` the error and it will print `"TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://localhost:5001/assets/SettingsView-4eff3305.js"` so I know which file failed the import.

In the `to` object I can find the name of the route which I was trying to access when the error occured.

So, final questions:

- Is there a way to overwrite the route's component import and then retry route navigation?
  *Also, I'm afraid this solution is too much of a hack. And is there a risk that the manifest.json file will get cached as well? Then the whole workaround would be useless.*
- Is there any better designed way to deal with this situation in Vue/Vite? Something I'm missing in the Vite config file?

Thank you.

PS: Related question for the same code-splitting problem that didn't get an answer yet: [Vue3 + Vite dynamic import fails in production build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75832729/vue3-vite-dynamic-import-fails-in-production-build)
And a more concise explanation of why the error occurs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74057337/22028865 in case the different wording helps :).

Answer (score 0):

There is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/11804) for this with a lot of discussion and suggestions. I like [this approach](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/11804#issuecomment-1406182566), where you force a page reload to the URL that could not be resolved:

```
router.onError((error, to) => {
  if (error.message.includes('Failed to fetch dynamically imported module')) {
    window.location = to.fullPath
  }
})
```

It is almost seamless and has minimal overhead on your side.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.
I've already tried my best to comprehend that Github thread. 
My biggest trouble is that I want to avoid having to reload or use window navigation - the ideal thing would be to sort out the issue in the `router.onError` catch, and from there continue router navigation smoothly.

Comment: Oh, right, I didn't address it directly. I think it is an interesting idea, but my guess is that implementing it will cost a lot of time to ultimately build something that is sometimes slightly better than a silent reload, but sometimes isn't. Considering that you get the reload for next to nothing, this would not be a hard decision for me. But if you go for it, godspeed, of course!